# How can I parse the JSON response from Microsoft Graph Api List Chat into the textbox

Tags: c#, json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams-js

This is the code what I have tried.

Based on my limited knowledge it cannot display JSON response of Microsoft.Graph API, it just appears the message box with the content of Microsoft.Graph.User.

How can I parse the JsonResponse into the textbox.

Documentation of ListChat:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scopes = new[] { "Chat.ReadBasic", "Chat.ReadWrite", "Chat.Read" };

    // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
    // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
    var tenantId = "5xxxx3-3xxa-4xxx1-9xx0c-exxxb0";
    // Value from app registration
    var clientId = "35xxxx-5xxx2-4xx9-8500-63xxxxaf";

    // using Azure.Identity;
    var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
        AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

    var userName = "xx.xxxx@xxxi.com";
    var password = "Axxxxx@";

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.usernamepasswordcredential
    var userNamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
                userName, password, tenantId, clientId, options);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes);

    var request = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    String txt = request.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(txt);
}
```

[image: In Correct Response]

Comment: It looks like you don't have a JSON response, but an object of type `Microsoft.Graph.User` which does not implement it's own `ToString()`, that's why you get the name of the type when using `ToString()`.

Comment: Can I know how can I get the JSON response about List Chat on my code? I a bit confuse about the documentation @RedFox

Comment: If your **really** need the data as JSON, use a Json serializer to convert it to a JSON string. If you just want to display some data, I would not recommend it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try to deserialize it with Newtonsoft.Json

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

To do that you need a class with the same properties as the .json file. So something like:

```
public class Response
{
    public List<Value> Values {get;set;}
}

public class Value
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Topic {get;set;
    .....
    public ChatViewPoint ChatViewPoint {get;set;}
}
public class ChatViewPoint
{
    public bool IsHidden {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

After you created the classes you can try to deserialize the string to the given datamodel.

Hope it works

Answer (score 1):

You can create `HttpRequestMessage`, send this message using `HttpProvider` on `GraphServiceClient` to get a response and read the content. It should be json.

For current user

```
var httpMessage = graphClient.Me.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(httpMessage);
var jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show(jsonContent);
```

For chats

```
var httpMessage = graphClient.Me.Chats.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(httpMessage);
var jsonContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
MessageBox.Show(jsonContent);
```

Comment: if I wnt to show the response of create chat by following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http is it be able to show it with http request message method

Answer (score 0):

At

```
  var request = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

you do **not** have `JSON` which you have to parse, but an object of type `Microsoft.Graph.User`.
Since this object does not implement it's own `.ToString()` it gives you the result of the base implementation which is it's object type name.

If you really need the object as `JSON`, you can use a `JSON`serializer like [Newstonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) provides and use it to serialize your data to a `JSON` string.

If you want to display data of the user you have to access it's properties and display their values.